# How do i save an associated Object in Rails / Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Lets say i have two models: Team --1---n--> Player
In Words: A Team can have many Players. A Player belongs to a Team.

On the page that shows the Team-Data i want to place a link 'create Player'.

In the Players controller, how do I create the Player so that it is associated with the Team, viewed where the 'create Player' link was placed?

Do I have to

**1.** pass the Team-ID to the 'create Players' controller and

**2.** look up the Team using the Team-ID and then

**3.** something like this: `@new_player = @team.players.build(...)`

Can I use one of the resource routes for the 'create Player' link?

Answer (score 2):

If teams and players will be added via separate forms:

You can either include the team_id in the form for the new player or nest the route to players in the scope of teams and pull the team_id from the url params like `params[:team_id]`.

Nested players route:

```
    resources :teams do
      resources :players
    end
```

In your team/show view (team details page), Create Player link:

```
    <%= link_to 'Create Player', new_team_player_path(@team) %>
```

In the players form:

```
    <% form_for [@team, @player] do |f| %>
    <!-- your form here -->
    <%- end -%>
```

In the Players controller:

```
    def new
      @team = Team.find params[:team_id]
      @player = Player.new
    end

    def create
      @player = Player.new params[:player]
      @player.team_id = params[:team_id] # => if just grabbing the id from the url params
      if @player.save
        # flash and redirect
      else
        # show form again
      end
    end
```

Otherwise, see the railscast about nested attributes mentioned by @Antoine for specifying both new team and player details on one form. (I think what you're looking for is the first option with two forms but I could be way off.)

For more information about nested resource routing, see the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). To see what routes are available in your application, run `rake routes` from the command line at the root of your app.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help!
It was surprisingly hard to find a hint on such a beginners question :-)
After running Goggles server hot, I also found this tutorial site
[ruby-rails-3-model-1-many-association](http://jonathanhui.com/ruby-rails-3-model-1-many-association)
There's a lot more goodies on that site. Could be usefull for other Newbies...
But anyway, than you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think nested_attributes can help you.

Watch [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) railscast about it.

Comment: Thank you!
I appreciate that hint!